# How to rip an asx stream - preferably free

Tags: windows, streaming, ripping, winamp

I am trying to rip an asx stream through winamp (at present) on Windows XP (or Vista if necessary) using stream ripper, however it complains I have an Invalid URL (though the stream itself plays).

I am not interested in one of the many products available for $$ that tend to 'spam' the top google results for this sort of thing.

Is there any simple way to rip an asx stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My investigation has lead me to 2 good alternatives

If you get the asx file and copy the mms address in it (it is, in fact just a text file) to [Orbit](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/), it will download to an ob! file. Once the recording is finished, the extension can be changed to a wma and used.

Also [SDP](http://sdp.ppona.com/) from works great, and rips to an asf.

Both these outputs can be converted to an output of your choice with [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is useful to help you with this. A lot of streams in this format I have seen have DRM, Commercials, and other measures to make it hard to rip.

Comment: +1 for VLC, although in this exact occasion it did not work as it was trying to access the asf stream referenced in the asx, which, for this occasion was invalid stream. Great tool though, I am a regular user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
mplayer -dumpstream URL-STREAMING -dumpfile FILE-TO-SAVE
```

To listen to the recording you can use:

```
mplayer  FILE-TO-SAVE
```

If the streaming is in RealAudio format do this to get a WAV file:

```
mplayer -cache 10 -ao pcm -aofile stream.wav  rtsp://XXXX/stream.rm
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers here worked for me, in the case of one particular asx stream, probably because the applications (Orbit, VLC, mplayer, etc.) cannot cope with WMA codecs.

Eventually I worked out how to do it with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and wrote a [detailed explanation](https://superuser.com/a/1200493/650972). To summarize: open the asx file in a text-editor, find the mms URL, replace mms with rtsp, install ffmpeg, and then do something like

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://aaa.bbb.ccc/ddd.asf myFile.mp3
```

Comment: what does that explanation say?

Comment: You can click on the link to find out. Do you mean that I should duplicate my detailed explanation here? Or write a summary here? I have added a summary now.

Comment: this summary seems perfect, merci ... and +1 ...!

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Hidownload 7](http://www.hidownload.net/)

> HiDownload is the easiest way to rip streaming video and audio from windows streaming media server through MMS, RTSP and HTTP protocols, suppport all the window stream formats(wmv, asf, wma, **asx**, wvx, wax, ...)

Comment: Sorry this is a pay product, I was really interested in a free alternative

Answer (score -2):

open asx file with notepad. there is your wmv/wma etc. download link.